# Is it possible to grant another AWS user login administrator access for all services?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to grant logina@foo.com full access to all services in loginb@foo.com for AWS Web Services?  I have a couple different folks working on my team and I wanted to make it easy for them to do what they need to do in our sandbox.

Thanks!

Comment: Some thing like https://aws.amazon.com/iam/?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using something@foo.com to log into your AWS account, you need to stop doing that right now, and set up an IAM (Identity and Access Management) account instead.

There is a best practices document [here](http://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Security_Best_Practices.pdf) - you want to look at the section under "Manage AWS Accounts, IAM Users, Groups, and Roles" - but in a nutshell:

- Use 2 factor authentication on the root account
- create IAM accounts for daily use.  If you grant admin access to an IAM account, it should probably be set up with 2 factor authentication as well
- turn on CloudTrail.  Yes, it will cost you a few cents a month.  But if you ever need it, you'll really, really wish you had it.
- Never, ever, ever check access keys and secrets into a public repository.  (The cost for violating this one will be around $5k/hour.)
- set up a billing alarm.  Estimate what you'll be spending a month, and set up alarms at 25%, 50%, 75% and 100%.  That way if something does go wrong (or you accidentally spin up an r3.8xlarge) you'll get a notice quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Every account only has a single 'root', but using "Identity and Access Management" you can create and account users and grant console login and adminstrative privileges inside the AWS console.

- Look under the services tab for one named "IAM".
- Select 'Users' from and press the blue 'create new users' button
- Add a user login name

Once the user's created

- Select the user and set a password via "manage password"--without this they can't log in
- Press the 'Permissions" tab for the users and select Attach policy
- Give the user the 'Administrtor Access' policy.

The user should then be able to log into the AWS console with admin privs and use the API if they want